# Combine identical child elements in XSLT

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt

Hi first of all i am learning the complex XSLT iteration and write now i am stucked with a query in which i have identilcal information under Tag Information and the only different tag is BookingClassAvail with different attribute values and i want to combine into one keeping the Information tags as separate.

XML:

```
      <Availability>
        <Success/>
        <Information xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
          <DepDateTime>2012-10-27</DepDateTime>
          <OrigLocation LocationCode="DEL" />
          <DestLocation LocationCode="BOM" />
          <OrigDestinationOptions>
            <OrigDestinationOption>
              <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-10-27A12:35:00" ArrDateTime="2012-10-27A14:05:00" StopQuantity="0" FlightNumber="152" JourneyDuration="90" Ticket="eTicket">
                <DepAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="" />
                <ArrAirport LocationCode="BOM" Terminal="" />
                <OperatingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
                <Equipment AirEquipType="A320" />
                <MarketingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
                <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="T" ResBookDesigQuantity="180" />
              </FlightSegment>
            </OrigDestinationOption>
            <OrigDestinationOption>
              <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-10-27A12:35:00" ArrDateTime="2012-10-27A14:05:00" StopQuantity="0" FlightNumber="152" JourneyDuration="90" Ticket="eTicket">
                <DepAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="" />
                <ArrAirport LocationCode="BOM" Terminal="" />
                <OperatingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
                <Equipment AirEquipType="A320" />
                <MarketingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
                <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="B" ResBookDesigQuantity="80" />
              </FlightSegment>
            </OrigDestinationOption>


            <OrigDestinationOption>
              <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-10-28A10:35:00" ArrDateTime="2012-10-27A14:05:00" StopQuantity="0" FlightNumber="152" JourneyDuration="90" Ticket="eTicket">
                <DepAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="" />
                <ArrAirport LocationCode="BOM" Terminal="" />
                <OperatingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
                <Equipment AirEquipType="A320" />
                <MarketingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
                <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="B" ResBookDesigQuantity="80" />
              </FlightSegment>
            </OrigDestinationOption>
          </OrigDestinationOptions>
        </Information>
        <Information xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
          <DepDateTime>2012-11-05</DepDateTime>
          <OrigLocation LocationCode="BOM" />
          <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL" />
          <OrigDestinationOptions>
            <OrigDestinationOption>
              <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-11-05T08:35:00" ArrDateTime="2012-11-05T09:40:00" StopQuantity="0" FlightNumber="993" JourneyDuration="65" Ticket="eTicket">
                <DepAirport LocationCode="BOM" Terminal="" />
                <ArrAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="" />
                <OperatingAirline CompanyShortName="GR" />
                <Equipment AirEquipType="A320" />
                <MarketingAirline CompanyShortName="GR" />
                <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="T" ResBookDesigQuantity="180" />
              </FlightSegment>
            </OrigDestinationOption>
            <OrigDestinationOption>
              <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-11-05A08:35:00" ArrDateTime="2012-11-05A16:15:00" StopQuantity="0" FlightNumber="666" JourneyDuration="75" Ticket="eTicket">
                <DepAirport LocationCode="BOM" Terminal="" />
                <ArrAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="" />
                <OperatingAirline CompanyShortName="MM" />
                <Equipment AirEquipType="A320" />
                <MarketingAirline CompanyShortName="MM" />
                <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="Y" ResBookDesigQuantity="180" />
              </FlightSegment>
            </OrigDestinationOption>
          </OrigDestinationOptions>
        </Information>
      </Availability>
```

Want an output as below:

```
    <Availability>
      <Success/>
      <Information xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <DepDateTime>2012-10-27</DepDateTime>
        <OrigLocation LocationCode="DEL" />
        <DestLocation LocationCode="BOM" />
        <OrigDestinationOptions>
          <OrigDestinationOption>
            <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-10-27A12:35:00" ArrDateTime="2012-10-27A14:05:00" StopQuantity="0" FlightNumber="152" JourneyDuration="90" Ticket="eTicket">
              <DepAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="" />
              <ArrAirport LocationCode="BOM" Terminal="" />
              <OperatingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
              <Equipment AirEquipType="A320" />
              <MarketingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
              <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="T" ResBookDesigQuantity="180" />
              <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="B" ResBookDesigQuantity="80" />
            </FlightSegment>
          </OrigDestinationOption>

         <!-- since the DepDateTime has different date hence not combined in the above flightsegment -->

            <OrigDestinationOption>
              <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-10-28A10:35:00" ArrDateTime="2012-10-27A14:05:00" StopQuantity="0" FlightNumber="152" JourneyDuration="90" Ticket="eTicket">
                <DepAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="" />
                <ArrAirport LocationCode="BOM" Terminal="" />
                <OperatingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
                <Equipment AirEquipType="A320" />
                <MarketingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
                <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="B" ResBookDesigQuantity="80" />
              </FlightSegment>
            </OrigDestinationOption>
        </OrigDestinationOptions>
      </Information>
      <Information xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <DepDateTime>2012-11-05</DepDateTime>
        <OrigLocation LocationCode="BOM" />
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL" />
        <OrigDestinationOptions>
          <OrigDestinationOption>
            <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-11-05T08:35:00" ArrDateTime="2012-11-05T09:40:00" StopQuantity="0" FlightNumber="993" JourneyDuration="65" Ticket="eTicket">
              <DepAirport LocationCode="BOM" Terminal="" />
              <ArrAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="" />
              <OperatingAirline CompanyShortName="GR" />
              <Equipment AirEquipType="A320" />
              <MarketingAirline CompanyShortName="GR" />
              <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="T" ResBookDesigQuantity="180" />
              <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="Y" ResBookDesigQuantity="180" />
            </FlightSegment>
          </OrigDestinationOption>
        </OrigDestinationOptions>
      </Information>
    </Availability>
```

If you see above the tags BookingClassAvail  has different information for ResBookDesigCode and ResBookDesigQuantity so it need to be stacked row wise.

```
<BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="T" ResBookDesigQuantity="180" />
<BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="B" ResBookDesigQuantity="80" />
```

Also if any information in  comes different than it should comes as separate flight segment.

Also note that above one   tag for outbound flight and other information for inbound flight and need to be kept as seperate and only the  need to be merged.

Thanks a million in advance.

---

Sean i have used your suggested solution and i faced an error as "White space cannot be stripped from input documents that have already been loaded. Provide the input document as an XmlReader instead."

XML:

```
        <Availability>
  <Success/>
  <Information xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <DepDateTime>2012-10-27</DepDateTime>
    <OrigLocation LocationCode="DEL" />
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BOM" />
    <OrigDestinationOptions>
      <OrigDestinationOption>
        <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-10-27T12:35:00" ArrivalDateTime="2012-10-27T14:05:00" StopQuantity="0" FlightNumber="152" JourneyDuration="90" Ticket="eTicket">
          <DepAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="" />
          <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="BOM" Terminal="" />
          <OperatingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
          <Equipment AirEquipType="A123" />
          <MarketingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
          <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="O" ResBookDesigQuantity="40" />
        </FlightSegment>
      </OrigDestinationOption>
      <OrigDestinationOption>
        <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-10-27T12:35:00" ArrivalDateTime="2012-10-27T14:05:00" StopQuantity="0" FlightNumber="152" JourneyDuration="90" Ticket="eTicket">
          <DepAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="" />
          <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="BOM" Terminal="" />
          <OperatingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
          <Equipment AirEquipType="A123" />
          <MarketingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
          <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="T" ResBookDesigQuantity="180" />
        </FlightSegment>
      </OrigDestinationOption>
      <OrigDestinationOption>
        <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-10-27T19:10:00" ArrivalDateTime="2012-10-27T20:10:00" StopQuantity="0" FlightNumber="158" JourneyDuration="60" Ticket="eTicket">
          <DepAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="" />
          <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="BOM" Terminal="" />
          <OperatingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
          <Equipment AirEquipType="A123" />
          <MarketingAirline CompanyShortName="A1" />
          <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="D" ResBookDesigQuantity="50" />
        </FlightSegment>
      </OrigDestinationOption>
    </OrigDestinationOptions>
  </Information>
  <Information xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <DepDateTime>2012-11-05</DepDateTime>
    <OrigLocation LocationCode="BOM" />
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL" />
    <OrigDestinationOptions>
      <OrigDestinationOption>
        <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-11-05T15:00:00" ArrivalDateTime="2012-11-05T16:15:00" StopQuantity="0" FlightNumber="666" JourneyDuration="75" Ticket="eTicket">
          <DepAirport LocationCode="BOM" Terminal="" />
          <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="" />
          <OperatingAirline CompanyShortName="M1" />
          <Equipment AirEquipType="A123" />
          <MarketingAirline CompanyShortName="M1" />
          <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="Y" ResBookDesigQuantity="180" />
        </FlightSegment>
      </OrigDestinationOption>
      <OrigDestinationOption>
        <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-11-05T15:00:00" ArrivalDateTime="2012-11-05T16:15:00" StopQuantity="0" FlightNumber="666" JourneyDuration="75" Ticket="eTicket">
          <DepAirport LocationCode="BOM" Terminal="" />
          <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="" />
          <OperatingAirline CompanyShortName="M1" />
          <Equipment AirEquipType="A123" />
          <MarketingAirline CompanyShortName="M1" />
          <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="Y" ResBookDesigQuantity="180" />
        </FlightSegment>
      </OrigDestinationOption>
    </OrigDestinationOptions>
  </Information>
</Availability>
```

XSLT used :

```
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ot="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl ot">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:key name="kSegment" match="ot:OrigDestinationOption"
                           use="concat( ot:FlightSegment[1]/@DepDateTime,
                                          '|', generate-id(..))" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ot:OrigDestinationOptions">
    <xsl:variable name="options" select="generate-id()" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="
     ot:OrigDestinationOption[
       generate-id()=generate-id(key('kSegment',
        concat( ot:FlightSegment[1]/@DepDateTime,
                '|', $options))[1])]" mode="group" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ot:OrigDestinationOption" mode="group">
    <xsl:variable name="group" select="key('kSegment',
        concat( ot:FlightSegment[1]/@DepDateTime,'|', generate-id(..)))" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::ot:FlightSegment)]"/>
      <FlightSegment xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <xsl:apply-templates
          select="ot:FlightSegment[1]/@*  |
               ot:FlightSegment[1]/*[not(self::ot:BookingClassAvail)] |
               $group/ot:FlightSegment/ot:BookingClassAvail" />
      </FlightSegment>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Error faced :

"White space cannot be stripped from input documents that have already been loaded. Provide the input document as an XmlReader instead."

Comment: This kind of problem is normally called "grouping" and if you search under that keyword you will find many examples. For XSLT 2.0 it's usually achieved with the for-each-group instruction; for XSLT 1.0 there's a technique called "Muenchian grouping" which you can find in most XSLT textbooks or by googling.

Comment: Ya but i am using XSLT 1.0 and like to know the easiest way saving my time.Help will be appreciated.

Comment: i tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682962/recursively-combine-identical-sibling-elements-in-xslt and it does the job partially as it end it up with all the grouping inside one Information tag but as mentioned the information tag should be kept seperate for outbound and inbound.

Comment: Your narrative contradicts your supplied example. In your sample input document, the last flight segment has a departure time of '2012-11-05A15:00:00'. You merged that segment with one of a different time, and now that time does not exist in your expected output document.

Comment: Thanks Sean that was my typo apology for the same ,i have corrected it.Please help me out with solution really apreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ot="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl ot">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="kSegment" match="ot:OrigDestinationOption"
                             use="concat( ot:FlightSegment[1]/@DepDateTime,
                                          '|', generate-id(..))" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ot:OrigDestinationOptions">
 <xsl:variable name="options" select="generate-id()" />
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="
     ot:OrigDestinationOption[
       generate-id()=generate-id(key('kSegment',
        concat( ot:FlightSegment[1]/@DepDateTime,
                '|', $options))[1])]" mode="group" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ot:OrigDestinationOption" mode="group">
  <xsl:variable name="group" select="key('kSegment',
        concat( ot:FlightSegment[1]/@DepDateTime,'|', generate-id(..)))" /> 
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::ot:FlightSegment)]"/>
   <FlightSegment xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
     <xsl:apply-templates
       select="ot:FlightSegment[1]/@*  |
               ot:FlightSegment[1]/*[not(self::ot:BookingClassAvail)] |
               $group/ot:FlightSegment/ot:BookingClassAvail" />
   </FlightSegment>  
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...when applied to this input** (a cut-down version of the OP's supplied document)...

```
<Availability>
    <Information xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <OrigDestinationOptions>
        <OrigDestinationOption>
            <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-10-27A12:35:00" Ticket="eTicket">
                <DepAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal=""/>
                <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="T" ResBookDesigQuantity="180"/>
            </FlightSegment>
        </OrigDestinationOption>
        <OrigDestinationOption>
            <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-10-27A12:35:00" Ticket="eTicket">
                <DepAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal=""/>
                <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="B" ResBookDesigQuantity="80"/>
            </FlightSegment>
        </OrigDestinationOption>
    </OrigDestinationOptions>
</Information>
<Information xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
<OrigDestinationOptions>
    <OrigDestinationOption>
        <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-10-28A10:35:00" Ticket="eTicket">
            <DepAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal=""/>
            <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="B" ResBookDesigQuantity="80"/>
        </FlightSegment>
    </OrigDestinationOption>
</OrigDestinationOptions>
</Information>
</Availability>
```

**...yields...**

```
<Availability>
  <Information xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <OrigDestinationOptions>
      <OrigDestinationOption>
        <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-10-27A12:35:00" Ticket="eTicket">
          <DepAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="" />
          <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="T" ResBookDesigQuantity="180" />
          <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="B" ResBookDesigQuantity="80" />
        </FlightSegment>
      </OrigDestinationOption>
    </OrigDestinationOptions>
  </Information>
  <Information xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <OrigDestinationOptions>
      <OrigDestinationOption>
        <FlightSegment DepDateTime="2012-10-28A10:35:00" Ticket="eTicket">
          <DepAirport LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="" />
          <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="B" ResBookDesigQuantity="80" />
        </FlightSegment>
      </OrigDestinationOption>
    </OrigDestinationOptions>
  </Information>
</Availability>
```

### Notes

1. The grouping key is the product of the the parent OrigDestinationOptions node and the Flight departure time.
2. It is assumed that each OrigDestinationOption contains precisely one FlightSegment.
3. It is assumed that when FlightSegments in the same group are to be merged, the only different information over all members of the group that needs to be preserved is the BookingClassAvail element.
4. This is not a super-generic solution, but that is reasonable considering the lack of definition in the problem articulation. If you need a more general solution, you need to be more precise about the input structure and the rules of transformation.

Comment: Sean thanks for your help you are the man.                           Just little issue when i used your xslt on my xml (check my quetion i have edited it with your solution) its throwing error as ""White space cannot be stripped from input documents that have already been loaded. Provide the input document as an XmlReader instead."

Comment: Sean what i found is this error coming when <xsl:strip-space elements="*" /> is used ,can i remove it or if you can let me know its impact after removing it.

Comment: Sean you are Genius.Cheers Yatharth

Comment: Thanks. You can remove xsl:strip-space without harm. The effect of this instruction is to remove pure white space text nodes from the input document when viewed as an infoset by the XSLT processor.